# replicating elements in list

Tags: python, list, replication

Say I have this

```
b = 3
l = [1, 2]
```

I want to modify l so that each element appears as many times as b. So that:

```
l = [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2]
```

I used this:

```
for x in l:
  for m in range(b):
    l.append(x)
```

But it resulted in an infinite loop.
Any help would be appreciated.
I would prefer you guys to give ideas rather than give me the code.
Thanks.

Comment: I suggest closing this question as a duplicate of [Repeating elements of a list n times](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24225072/7851470). It was asked a bit later but has more traffic, votes, and answers.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

My 2 cents :

Another way to achieve this would also be to take advantage of the fact you can multiply lists in Python.

```
>>> l = [1, 2, 3]
>>> [1, 2, 3] * 3
[1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3]
```

A simple call to the `sorted` function allows to sort it back :

```
>>> b = 3    
>>> l = [1, 2]
>>> sorted(l * b)
[1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2]
```

Comment: This is needlessly complex, and only works if the original input is sorted.

Answer (score 9):

You can use a list comprehension:

```
>>> b = 3
>>> x = [1, 2]
>>> l = [x for x in l for _ in range(b)]
>>> l
[1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2]
>>>
```

Now, to fix your issue:

You might want to create a new list, and append to that list

```
>>> l  = [1, 2]
>>> y = []
>>> b = 3
>>> for x in l:
...   for i in range(b):
...     y.append(x)
...
>>> y
[1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2]
```

I would prefer the list comprehension method though.

Answer (score 2):

Your main problem is that it's unsafe to modify the list as you iterate over it. You could work around that by building a new list - the various itertools and comprehension answers show some ways to do that, or you could just use your `for` loop if you like.

Since you asked for ideas rather than code, I'll point out that `itertools.repeat` is another useful tool. It should be fairly obvious how to use that to multiply a given element of the list - you'd then need to figure out how to combine the iterators for each element of your list into a single list. For that, `itertools.chain` is useful, using either the `*` syntax to unpack a sequence of `repeat` iterators or the `itertools.chain.from_iterable` constructor.

This would essentially be the same idea as freyrs' answer, just creating a `repeat` iterator for each element rather than creating and multiplying a list for each element.

Comment: what if i want to create a new list instead of modifying the existing one by using a for loop?

Comment: The simplest way would be as karthikr's answer shows - declare a new empty list before the for loop and append to that.

Answer (score 1):

Can use itertools for this:

```
from itertools import chain
list(chain(*[[i]*b for i in l]))
```

Which gives output:

```
[1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2]
```