# Python Dictionary Multiplication

Tags: python, list, dictionary

Say we have this:

```
dict = {1:[2, 3]}
m = 4
new = {1:[]} # to save time, the keys in "new" were obtained from "dict"
```

I wanna use "dict" to make "new" so each of the values appear in list of "dict" as many times as "m" so that:

```
new = {1:[2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3]} # values appear "m" times
```

How can I achieve this by using for loops? It gets kinda confusing for me as I used a lot of for loops, any help would be appreciated.
I would prefer if you guys give ideas rather that give me the code.

Answer (score 3):

```
data = {1: [2,3]}
m = 4
new = {k:[n for n in lst for i in range(m)] for k,lst in data.items()}
```

Answer (score 2):

if you don't care about order:

```
data = {1: [2,3]}
m = 4

# gives {1:[2,3,2,3,2,3,2,3]}
new_data = { k:v*m for k,v in data.items()}
```

Answer (score 0):

[replicating elements in list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20276138/replicating-elements-in-list) should give you a good idea of how to proceed in this case.

Python allows you to just "multiply" whatever you want to repeat by the number of repetitions.

edit: Wow.. wait - didn't you post on the "replicating elements in list-thread" already?

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> from itertools import chain, repeat
>>> data = {1: [2,3]}
>>> m = 4
>>> {k: list(chain.from_iterable(repeat(i, m) for i in data[k])) for k in data}
{1: [2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3]}
```