# Repeating elements of a list n times

Tags: python

How do I repeat each element of a list `n` times and form a new list? For example:

```
x = [1,2,3,4]
n = 3

x1 = [1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4]
```

`x * n` doesn't work

```
for i in x[i]:
    x1 = n * x[i]
```

There must be a simple and smart way.

Comment: Related questions: [Circular list iterator in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23416381/7851470), [Duplicate elements in a list](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14878538/7851470), [Repeat a list within a list X number of times](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16095865/7851470), [Best way to extend a list with itself N times](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46560385/7851470).

Comment: Also: [How to repeat each of a Python list's elements n times with itertools only?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45799233/7851470)

Answer (score 69, accepted):

In case you really want result as list, and generator is not sufficient:

```
import itertools
lst = range(1,5)
list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(itertools.repeat(x, 3) for x in lst))

Out[8]: [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4]
```

Comment: For those interested in efficiency, this is one of the (if not **the** ) **fastest method** listed in this post.

Comment: check my answer @S3DEV

Answer (score 159):

The ideal way is probably `numpy.repeat`:

```
In [16]:

import numpy as np  
x1=[1,2,3,4]
In [17]:

np.repeat(x1,3)
Out[17]:
array([1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4])
```

Comment: for the noobs, you're going to need to `import numpy as np` at the head of your file ;-)

Comment: For the newbs, you also would need to do a `pip install numpy` before being able to run the script. ;-)

Answer (score 67):

You can use list comprehension:

```
[item for item in x for i in range(n)]
```

---

```
>>> x = [1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> n = 3
>>> new = [item for item in x for i in range(n)]
#[1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4]
```

Comment: pandas.Index.repeat just a call to np.repeat

Comment: @AndyHayden, but the OP tagged [tag:pandas]

Comment: I see that, But `pandas.Index.repeat` __is__ np.repeat (as a ndarray method), there is no pandas magic here, it seems silly to call pandas for the sake of it (especially when it's not an Index!). Better to just do `np.array([1, 2, 3, 4]).repeat(3)`.

Comment: I don't the question has anything specifically to do with pandas tbh (I see you've already removed/rolled back a tag edit)...

Comment: @AndyHayden I first removed it because I thought it was irrelevant. But now, I see that the OP might want to **solve it with [tag:pandas].**

Comment: Then please try your code with pandas objects e.g. Series or DataFrame. It doesn't work.

Comment: This comment could(?) be improved by adding run times for the various methods

Comment: This is my preferred solution.

Answer (score 19):

A simpler way to achieve this to multiply the list `x` with `n` and sort the resulting list. e.g.

```
>>> x = [1,2,3,4]
>>> n = 3
>>> a = sorted(x*n)
>>> a
>>> [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4]
```

Comment: For me this worked perfectly, because I also wanted to sort the list after the multiplication.

Comment: Won't work if order is to be preserved `x = list('NESW')`.

Answer (score 10):

A nested list-comp works here:

```
>>> [i for i in range(10) for _ in xrange(3)]
[0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8, 9, 9, 9]
```

Or to use your example:

```
>>> x = [1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> n = 3
>>> [i for i in x for _ in xrange(n)]
[1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4]
```

Answer (score 3):

```
zAxe=[]
for i in range(5):
    zAxe0 =[i] * 3
    zAxe +=(zAxe0) # append allows accimulation of data
```

Comment: Thanks for this trick; `zAxe +=(zAxe0) # append allows accimulation of data`

Answer (score 3):

```
 [myList[i//n] for i in range(n*len(myList))]
```

Answer (score 3):

way 1:

```py
def foo():
    for j in [1, 3, 2]:
        yield from [j]*5
```

way 2:

```py
from itertools import chain
l= [3, 1, 2]
chain(*zip(*[l]*3))
```

way 3:

```py
sum(([i]*5 for i in [2, 1, 3]), [])
```

Answer (score 3):

This will solve your issue:

```
x=[1,2,3,4]
n = 3
x = sorted(x * n)
```

Comment: Welcome to the site, but your solution is the same as an [existing one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48179817/6306190).

Comment: This solution is broken for unsorted lists.

Answer (score 1):

```
import itertools

def expand(lst, n):
    lst = [[i]*n for i in lst]
    lst = list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(lst))
    return lst

x=[1,2,3,4]
n=3
x1 = expand(x,3)

print(x1)
```

Gives:

```
[1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4]
```

Explanation:

Doing, `[3]*3` gives the result of `[3,3,3]`, replacing this with `n` we get `[3,3,3,...3] (n times)` Using a list comprehension we can go through each elem of the list and perform this operation, finally we need to flatten the list, which we can do by `list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(lst))`

Comment: `itertools.chain(*x)` these days should be written as `itertools.chain.from_iterable(x)`

Comment: No problem.  I see that one relatively frequently.  The problem with the former is that it resolves your iterable into a tuple by merit of the unpacking operator which partially defeats the wonderfully laziness of `itertools`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to modify the list in-place, the best way is to iterate from the back and assign a slice of what was previously one item to a list of that item `n` times.

This works because of slice assignment:

```
>>> ls = [1, 2, 3]
>>> ls[0: 0+1]
[1]
>>> ls[0: 0+1] = [4, 5, 6]
>>> ls
>>> [4, 5, 6, 2, 3]
```

```
def repeat_elements(ls, times):
    for i in range(len(ls) - 1, -1, -1):
        ls[i: i+1] = [ls[i]] * times
```

Demo usage:

```
>>> a = [1, 2, 3]
>>> b = a
>>> b
[1, 2, 3]
>>> repeat_elements(b, 3)
>>> b
[1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3]
>>> a
[1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3]
```

(If you don't want to modify it in-place, you can copy the list and return the copy, which won't modify the original. This would also work for other sequences, like `tuple`s, but is not lazy like the `itertools.chain.from_iterable` and `itertools.repeat` method)

```
def repeat_elements(ls, times):
    ls = list(ls)  # Makes a copy
    for i in range(len(ls) - 1, -1, -1):
        ls[i: i+1] = [ls[i]] * times
    return ls
```

Answer (score 0):

For base Python 2.7:

```
    from itertools import repeat
    def expandGrid(**kwargs):
        # Input is a series of lists as named arguments
        # output is a dictionary defining each combination, preserving names
        #
        # lengths of each input list
        listLens = [len(e) for e in kwargs.itervalues()] 
        # multiply all list lengths together to get total number of combinations
        nCombos = reduce((lambda x, y: x * y), listLens) 
        iDict = {}
        nTimesRepEachValue=1 #initialize as repeating only once
        for key in kwargs.keys():
            nTimesRepList=nCombos/(len(kwargs[key])*nTimesRepEachValue)
            tempVals=[] #temporary list to store repeated
            for v in range(nTimesRepList):
                indicesToAdd=reduce((lambda x,y: list(x)+list(y)),[repeat(x, nTimesRepEachValue) for x in kwargs[key]])
                tempVals=tempVals+indicesToAdd
            iDict[key] = tempVals
            # Accumulating the number of times needed to repeat each value
            nTimesRepEachValue=len(kwargs[key])*nTimesRepEachValue
        return iDict

    #Example usage:
    expandedDict=expandGrid(letters=["a","b","c","d"],nums=[1,2,3],both=["v",3])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
x=[1,2,3,4]
def f11(x,n):  
    l=[]
    for item in x:
        for i in range(n):
            l.append(item)
            
    return l

f11(x,2)
```

Answer (score 0):

If working with array is okay,

```
np.array([[e]*n for e in x]).reshape(-1)
```

In my opinion it is very readable.