# How to repeat each of a Python list's elements n times with itertools only?

Tags: python, performance, list, iteration, python-itertools

I have a list with numbers:
`numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4]`.

I would like to have a list where they repeat `n` times like so (for `n = 3`):

`[1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4]`.

The problem is that I would like to only use `itertools` for this, since I am very constrained in performance.

I tried to use this expression:

`list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(itertools.repeat(numbers, 3)))`

But it gives me this kind of result:

`[1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4]`

which is obviously not what I need.

Is there a way to do this with `itertools` only, without using sorting, loops and list comprehensions? The closest I could get is:

`list(itertools.chain.from_iterable([itertools.repeat(i, 3) for i in numbers]))`,

but it also uses list comprehension, which I would like to avoid.

Comment: Is there a reason why you are avoiding list comprehensions?  They are pretty fast and often as performant as `itertools`.

Comment: Same question but without restriction on itertools: [Repeating elements of a list n times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24225072/repeating-elements-of-a-list-n-times)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you don't want to use list comprehension, following is a pure (+`zip`) `itertools` method to do it -

```
from itertools import chain, repeat

list(chain.from_iterable(zip(*repeat(numbers, 3))))
# [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4]
```

Answer (score 13):

Firstly, using functions from `itertools` won't necessarily be faster than a list comprehension: you should benchmark.

Pure list comprehension approach:

```
>>> numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> [y for x in numbers for y in (x,)*3]
[1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4]
```

Using `chain.from_iterable()` with `repeat()` in a generator expression:

```
>>> from itertools import chain, repeat
>>> list(chain.from_iterable(repeat(n, 3) for n in numbers))
[1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4]
```

Using `chain.from_iterable()` and `zip()`:

```
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> list(chain.from_iterable(zip(*(numbers,)*3)))
[1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4]
```

Comment: I find this list comprehension a tad easier to understand, and is faster for larger repetition values: `[x for x in numbers for _ in range(3)]`. I suspect the lower iteration edge for the multiplication method is due to function call overhead of range.

Comment: @Mattwmaster58: You could make it slightly faster by replacing `range(3)` with `repeat(None, 3)`, but still the multiplication version wins.

Answer (score 3):

Think you were very close, just rewriting the comprehension to a generator:

```
n = 3
numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4]
list(itertools.chain.from_iterable((itertools.repeat(i, n) for i in numbers)))
```