# How to repeat elements in list n times?

Tags: arrays, julia, repeat

How do I repeat each element of a list n times and form a new list? For example:

```
x=[1,2,3,4]
n=3
```

Looking for:

```
[1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4]
```

Comment: Similar Python question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24225072

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An `inner` argument to [`repeat`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/arrays/#Base.repeat) is what I was looking for:

```
repeat([1, 2, 3, 4], inner = 3)
```

Answer (score 1):

Also list comprehension:

```
x = [1,2,3,4]
n = 3
result = [i for i in x for j in 1:n]
```