# Using List Comprehension To Repeat Entries in 2D Array

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

I have the following piece of code, with the goal of repeating every element of a 2D list a certain number of times:

```
empty =[]
l = [[1,2,3], [4,5,6]]
n = [2,3]
for i, _as in enumerate(l):
    for _a in _as:
        for _n in range(n[i]):
            empty.append(_a)

empty
> [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6]
```

I would like to try and write this in a single line list comprehension format.

I have made an attempt using using:

```
empty = [
         [
           [_a]*n[i] for _a in _as
         ] 
         for i, _as in enumerate(l) 
        ]

empty
> [[[1, 1], [2, 2], [3, 3]], [[4, 4, 4], [5, 5, 5], [6, 6, 6]]]
```

How may I correct the above code to provide the desired result?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Repeating elements of a list n times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24225072/repeating-elements-of-a-list-n-times)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

if you're just looking to convert your code into a list comprehension then just write your loops in their *original order*. This way you'll never forget how to get things done using *list comprehension*.

```
output = [
    _a
    for i, _as in enumerate(l)
    for _a in _as
    for _n in range(n[i])
]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a double list comprehension:

```
l = [[1,2,3], [4,5,6]]
n = [2, 3]
empty =[i for j in [[a]*f for b,f in zip(l,n) for a in b] for i in j]
print(empty)
```

Output:

```
[1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`itertools.repeat`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.repeat) to repeat the elements of each sublist with `n`, then [`itertools.chain.from_iterable`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable) to flatten the final list:

```py
>>> from itertools import chain, repeat
>>> l = [[1,2,3], [4,5,6]]
>>> ns = [2, 3]
>>> list(chain.from_iterable(repeat(x, n) for lst, n in zip(l, ns) for x in lst))
[1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6]
```