# Repeat a certain character from a list? (Python)

Tags: python

I was wondering if there was a way to repeat certain characters from a list.
For instance:

```py
characters = ['t' 'a' 'c' 'o']
print(characters)
```

That would print `['taco']`.
How would I get it to print `['tacooo']`?

Comment: Can you tell us the logic to get from `taco` to `tacooo` ?

Comment: it was just an example

Comment: Sure. What is the logic here?

Comment: duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24225072/repeating-elements-of-a-list-n-times/24225187)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Repeating elements of a list n times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24225072/repeating-elements-of-a-list-n-times)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to repeat character n times in n index look at this example:

```
characters = ['t','a','c','o']
print(''.join(characters[0:3])+characters[3]*3)
```

Just multiply n with a single index or to this for multiple then join the items. Then concatenate with +.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try this way to solve your problem.

```
characters = ['t', 'a', 'c', 'o']

result = ""

n=3

for i in range(len(characters)):
  if(characters[i] != 'o'):
    result = result+characters[i]
  else:
    result = result + (characters[i]*n)

print([result]);
```