# How to iterate the first index value twice before going to the next index position?

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, iterator

I'm trying to make a for loop that iterates each index twice before going to the next one, for example if I have the following list:

```
l = [1,2,3]
```

I would like to iterate it if it was in this way:

```
l = [1,1,2,2,3,3]
```

could someone help me with this problem please?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Repeating elements of a list n times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24225072/repeating-elements-of-a-list-n-times)

Comment: @Ynjxsjmh That's explicitly about creating a new list, while this one is about iterating and thus allows other solutions (like the currently top-voted generator solution).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most obvious thing would be a generator function that yields each item in the iterable twice:

```
def twice(arr):
   for val in arr:
       yield val
       yield val

for x in twice([1, 2, 3]):
    print(x)
```

If you need a list, then

```
l = list(twice([1, 2, 3]))
```

Answer (score 3):

You could make a list comprehension that repeats the elements and flattens the result:

```
l = [1,2,3]
repeat = 2

[n for i in l for n in [i]*repeat]
# [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can solve this by using NumPy.

```
import numpy as np

l = np.repeat([1,2,3],2)
```

Repeat repeats elements of an array the specified number of times. This also returns a NumPy array. This can be converted back to a list if you wish with `list(l)`. However, NumPy arrays act similar to lists so most of the time you don't need to change anything.

Comment: You also really, _really_ don't need Numpy for this.

Answer (score 2):

Unsurprisingly, [more-itertools](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#more_itertools.repeat_each) has that:

```
>>> from more_itertools import repeat_each
>>> for x in repeat_each([1, 2, 3]):
...     print(x)
... 
1
1
2
2
3
3
```

(It also has an optional second parameter for telling it how often to repeat each. For example `repeat_each([1, 2, 3], 5)`. Default is 2.)

Comment: Maybe Unsurprising…but somehow I'm always surprised at what's in there.

Answer (score 1):

```
l = [1, 2, 3]
lst = []

for x in l:
   for i in range(2):
      lst.append(x)
print(lst)
# [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3]
```